# Multiple summations of equal size with text below it in word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, equation-editor

I am trying to type a formula in word, consisting of two summations (Sigma's), both with subscript. Something like this:

[image]

However, in word, a summation sign with option to add something below it always adds empty space (a placeholder for content inside the summation). Therefore, i can get either this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

or just use subscripts:

[image]

However, is there a way to get the both sigmas the same size, with text under it. And if possible, a way to decrease the size of the sigmas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/1443038/1295075) answer, the workaround for this problem is easy, but you must insert the summation through the **right place**. So no copy/paste or drag and drop.

1. Place your first summation.

[image]

2. Click on the small square to the right of it.

[image]

3. Go to: `Design > Structures > Large operator` and insert your second summation.

[image]

Note: Don't put any characters after it outsite this equation field, because it will remove the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to insert the sum symbol:

[image]

Then click on the small square to the right so it becomes selected:

[image]

And then insert a new sum symbol:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to make different-size summations, or if this is possible.